# Generate many elements inside an array

Tags: javascript

I want to generate an array with many elements inside.

```js
const a = Array.from({length: 5}, (v, i) => {car:5});
console.log(a)
```

With the code above, i want to get this:

```js
[
{car:5},
{car:5},
{car:5},
{car:5},
{car:5}
]
```

...but now i get undefined. It is possible to get what i described using `Array.from()`?

Comment: @Sheelpriy that will create an array with a single object that put in all the slots. Changing one changes all.

Comment: @VLAZ, yes, right. but I thought this is what he asked for.

Comment: @Sheelpriy it's definitely *completely* different from the sample code provided.

Comment: @VLAZ ahh, now I got it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return object from arrow function, wrap it into curly bracket `()`

```js
const a = Array.from({length: 5}, (v, i) => ({car:5}));
console.log(a)
```